# What's the meaning of <column> element in <many-to-many> element?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I want to use this element to set automatic fields, like audit fields intercepted by an Interceptor. So, whats the purpose of column element inside the many-to-many element?

Comment: I think I figured it out. It is just another way to enter the columns of the relationship. A more detailed way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark as answered, as I commented above, it is just another way to enter the columns of the relationship. A more detailed way.

Answer (score 0):

nhibernate.info is always the best place to start looking.
check this out:
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-ofvalues